# git clone: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, cygwin

I just installed Git, eager to use it for the first time for "cloning" a project, but as soon as I tried my first ever command I receive this dreaded error message:

> fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly

The command I was trying to run was:

```
 git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/projects/platform/packages/apps/Browser.git/tree
```

Any idea why I am getting this fail?

BTW, I am using the latest cygwin 1.7.8 git 1.7.4 on Windows XP SP3 32-bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you should do instead is:

```
git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Browser.git
```

**Outputs**:

```
Cloning into Browser...
remote: Counting objects: 10361, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2394/2394), done.
remote: Total 10361 (delta 5024), reused 10254 (delta 4943)
Receiving objects: 100% (10361/10361), 4.67 MiB | 4.91 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5024/5024), done.
```

Comment: I just updated the URL. If you open http://android.git.kernel.org/ you'll see that there is no directory named *projects*. And you should always give *.git* file for clone.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too, but I am getting the same exact error. Is is possible that I am missing some component or configuration?

Comment: You are king. :)  Thanks so much!

Comment: We both cloned successfully at the same time, but you got that at 4.91 MiB/s and I got it at 237 KiB/s. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try `export CYGWIN=binmode`. I've run into that or a very similar problem. Cygwin sometimes has its issues. It's not perfect. Even after this fix. You need to do that export every login. Consider putting it in /etc/profile.

Comment: The `(no)binmode` option is obsolete. See http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html#cygwinenv-removed-options.

Comment: @ak2 Ah, thank you. I had been running since pre-1.7 so this is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by recycling my router.  I guess in my case it was some sort of connectivity problem.